# How to create an equation library, to be called like bibtex?

Tags: symbols, equations, glossaries

I am newby in LateX, but I want to create an stand alone document to be used as a equation library where I can select my equations by calling them by name, and finally produce a list of equations used in the working document, or a glossary with the equation and description. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The sounds like it has quite limited applicability, no?

Comment: @Mariano: Why? If you have to cite the same equations over and over again in several papers you can make good use of it. I would guess the `glossaries` package could be used for it, or using `biblatex` for it, somehow.

Comment: @Martin: Does anyone write sufficiently many papers containing the same equations (for I assume no one sanely *repeats* the same equation in a paper many times...), of sufficient complexity each to justofy not simply retyping them, to make this significative? Only the remarkable notational consistency implied such a feat implies is worthy of praise!

Comment: @Mariano: I published only five papers so far and already had the same idea. And then there are also: thesis, presentation and, if you are a lecture, class notes, etc... Re-typing is out of the question for more complex equation. Ok, then there is still Copy&Paste.

Answer (score 2):

can be improved for your needs

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{EQN}{H}{eqn}
\begin{document}

\begin{EQN}
\begin{equation}
 y=f(x)
\end{equation}
\caption{my first equation}
\end{EQN}

\begin{EQN}
\begin{equation}
 y=f(x)
\end{equation}
\caption{my second equation}
\end{EQN}

\listof{EQN}{my equations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think part of what the OP wants is to call equations several times, like you might cite the same book several times...

Answer (score 1):

Based on Herbert's answer, with glossaries package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{EQN}{H}{eqn}

\newcommand\eqcite[1]{%
\begin{EQN}%
\begin{equation}%
\glssymbol{#1}%
\end{equation}%
\caption{\glsentryname{#1}}
\end{EQN}
}

\loadglsentries{glossdata.tex}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\eqcite{eq1}
\eqcite{eq2}

\listof{EQN}{My equations}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Your database is in file *glossdata.tex*

```
\newglossaryentry{eq1}{
   name={First equation}
  ,symbol={y=f(x)}
  ,description={Some equation}
}
\newglossaryentry{eq2}{
   name={Second equation}
  ,symbol={y=a+f(x)}
  ,description={Another equation}
}
```

To get list of descriptions, you have to run some indexing program, makeglossaries, makeindex or xindy.

```
makeglossaries nameofyourdocument
```

[image: Equations, list of equations and glossary]